# CSS / Javascript Menu fixed position issue (when scrolling)

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, menu, fixed

Here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0sawc7vL/1/

And here lies the issue:

```
.topmenu-ul li ul {
    font-size: 0;
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 35px;
    left: -32px;
}
```

The menu is perfect as it is right now. The only issue is, when I have a page where I can scroll. The submenu (with the "dashboard" link and such) stay in position, because it is fixed. When I remove the "position=fixed" property, the whole menu is screwed up. Same when I change it to relative. Any suggestions?

Comment: change it to `position: absolute` https://jsfiddle.net/0sawc7vL/

Comment: I tried that before but it didn't work. Now I see why, because of the other CSS things I have :P I edited my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0sawc7vL/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
position:relative
```

to

```
nav class="nav"
```

element.

Answer (score 3):

You should change it like this

```
.topmenu-ul li ul {
    font-size: 0;
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: -32px;
}
```

Comment: I did try that as well but I now edited my fiddle because I have some additional css styling in there.

Comment: Awesome stuff, thanks a lot, wish I could check both as the accepted answer!

Comment: As long as his solution did fix your problem, he deserves it.